# how to read unstructured data separated by # in R

Tags: r

just a short question... anyone plz help me how to read the following text file in R..

if #(delimiter)is  next to one another... it means missing value...

any idea? or tip? thanks for your kind

> 20040215#680#-.6#7.6#1457#-7.3#735#1.2#340.3#13.6#1427#0#0##-7.3#735#7.6#1457##=
>   98829
>   18#680#.4#11.1#1541#-7.3#635#.9#130.1#6.6#1137#0#0##-7.3#635#11.1#1541##=
>   98834
>   20040221#680##########7#2#1600#1.7#559#7.3#1604##= 98835
>   20040222#680##########1#####6.8#1108##= 98836
>   20040223#680##########0#0####6.8#1602##= 98837

Comment: So you're saying that `#` is the file delimiter and it also represents NA values?  Can you please show what your example should look like after it's read into R?

Comment: And what did you try? It looks like `scan` and `strsplit` can help.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do a fairly neat job - just tell `read.table` to separate on hash and not to use hash as a comment (otherwise loads of things get lost as comments):

```
> read.table("hash.hsv",sep="#", comment="")
        V1  V2   V3   V4   V5   V6  V7  V8    V9  V10  V11 V12 V13  V14  V15
1 20040215 680 -0.6  7.6 1457 -7.3 735 1.2 340.3 13.6 1427   0   0   NA -7.3
2       18 680  0.4 11.1 1541 -7.3 635 0.9 130.1  6.6 1137   0   0   NA -7.3
3 20040221 680   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA    NA   NA   NA   7   2 1600  1.7
4 20040222 680   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA    NA   NA   NA   1  NA   NA   NA
5 20040223 680   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA    NA   NA   NA   0   0   NA   NA
  V16  V17  V18 V19     V20
1 735  7.6 1457  NA = 98829
2 635 11.1 1541  NA = 98834
3 559  7.3 1604  NA = 98835
4  NA  6.8 1108  NA = 98836
5  NA  6.8 1602  NA = 98837
```